# ESP32 DNS tunneling : how to intercept/forward traffic (promiscuous VS httpd VS l2TAP)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, wifi-configuration, sniffing

#### Context

I'm often abroad for both work and vacation, and I find myself in situations where internet access is limited or unavailable in many of the countries I visit. While there are often free WiFi networks available, they usually require users to log in using SMS verification or facebook/google credentials. Unfortunately, I don't always have a compatible SIM card for SMS verification, and I'm hesitant to provide personal credentials to access these networks.

#### What I Want to Do

I'm aiming to achieve DNS tunneling with my ESP32. Typically, when connecting to free WiFi networks, users are required to go through a login page or provide certain credentials. However, DNS queries are often not blocked by these networks. My objective is to :

- Have my phone/laptop connected to my ESP32
- Have my ESP32 Act as both an Access Point (for my devices to connect to) and a Station (for connecting to free WiFi)
- Listen for incoming requests (TCP/UDP) and forward them to my server via (forged/encapsulated) DNS requests.
- Allow the server to extract packets from the DNS requests, forward them to the correct IP, and respond back to the ESP32
- Respond back to the originating device (my phone/laptop).

In essence, the flow is:

```
My phone <--WiFi--> ESP32 <--WiFi--> Free WiFi <--DNS--> My server <----> Internet
```

#### The Problem

I have successfully implemented most aspects of this setup: establishing the AP and STA modes, DNS request forging, and handling responses from the server. However, I'm facing a challenge in capturing all requests sent from the phone to the ESP32. I have already tried a few potential approaches:

1. **Promiscuous Mode (WiFi Packets)**: Using **`promiscuous_rx_cb`** to listen to WiFi packets. However, this approach requires my server to forward requests to a real WiFi network, which doesn't seem optimal.
2. **HTTPD Server (Listen to Ports)**: Starting an HTTPD server (**`httpd_start`**) and proxying requests. However, this approach is limited to common ports (23, 80, 443, etc.) as I can't listen to all of than and managing multiple sockets could be complex.
3. **L2TAP (AP Interface Data Layer)**: Listening on the AP interface data layer, possibly using L2TAP. I've  tried with the example (**`softap_sta`**) provided by ESP-IDF, and I'm unsure how to proceed on this path. Nor do I know how to use the packets on my server.

#### My Question

Considering the options above, I'm seeking advice on the best (and possibly simpler) approach to achieve my goal.

Additionally, I'm wondering if my choice of server environment (Python on my server and ESP-IDF on my ESP32) impacts the decision.

If anyone has experience in this area, I'd greatly appreciate your insights on selecting the most effective approach and why you believe it would be the best fit for my use case. Thank you for your time and expertise